# most used timezones support in the web application

Tags: c#, date, time, timezone, iana

I have an application which helps users to book meetings (events). I have to provide users with an opportunity to choice his/her own time zone in order to accurately plan and change event dates as well as show his/her schedules. I have found the IANA list which consists of almost 400 time zones. What time zones should I use to cover the most amount of users as possible. According to my idea, users don't have to look for his/her time zone too long.

I've found some sites where about 100 time zones are used (more and fewer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping a time zone list small while still covering the entire world is indeed a challenging problem.  How you go about handling it is entirely up to you, of course.

One suggestion you might consider is to filter the lists by country (or region) first.  See [this demo](https://timezonepickerdemo.azurewebsites.net/) for how that might look in your application.

You can implement this using my [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneNames) library.  In particular, the `GetTimeZonesForCountry` method is ideally suited.  In addition to the country, you can optionally supply a threshold date to filter out historical time zones that aren't needed before that date.

For example, the following gets the time zones that are needed when scheduling a future event in Brazil.  It returns a dictionary where the key is the IANA time zone ID and the value is the localized display name to show to a user, in Brazilian Portuguese in this case.

```cs
var zones = TZNames.GetTimeZonesForCountry("BR", "pt-BR", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
```

Output:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| America/Rio_Branco | Horário do Acre |
| America/Manaus | Horário do Amazonas (Manaus) |
| America/Cuiaba | Horário do Amazonas (Cuiabá) |
| America/Bahia | Horário de Brasília (Bahia) |
| America/Sao_Paulo | Horário de Brasília (São Paulo) |
| America/Noronha | Horário de Fernando de Noronha |

See the readme on the [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneNames) site for more examples.

If you want a single list instead of filtering by country, a different approach you might consider is to use Windows display names, which have a much shorter list than IANA.  TimeZoneNames has these as well, and works whether you are hosted on Windows or not.

For example, the following gets the Windows display names for Brazilian Portugese and their associated IANA time zone IDs.

```cs
var displayNames = TZNames.GetDisplayNames("pt-BR", true);
```

Partial Output:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Etc/GMT+12 | (UTC-12:00) Linha de Data Internacional Oeste |
| Etc/GMT+11 | (UTC-11:00) Tempo Universal Coordenado-11 |
| America/Adak | (UTC-10:00) Ilhas Aleutas |
| Pacific/Honolulu | (UTC-10:00) Havaí |
| Pacific/Marquesas | (UTC-09:30) Ilhas Marquesas |
| America/Anchorage | (UTC-09:00) Alasca |
| Etc/GMT+9 | (UTC-09:00) Tempo Universal Coordenado-09 |
| America/Whitehorse | (UTC-07:00) Yukon |
| America/Tijuana | (UTC-08:00) Baja Califórnia |
| Etc/GMT+8 | (UTC-08:00) Tempo Universal Coordenado-08 |
| America/Los_Angeles | (UTC-08:00) Hora do Pacífico (EUA e Canadá) |
| America/Phoenix | (UTC-07:00) Arizona |
| America/Chihuahua | (UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan |
| America/Denver | (UTC-07:00) Hora das Montanhas (EUA e Canadá) |
| America/Guatemala | (UTC-06:00) América Central |
| America/Chicago | (UTC-06:00) Hora Central (EUA e Canadá) |

...

Comment: Do note that TimeZoneNames is a fairly large library.  It should be fine on a server though.  Also, .NET doesn't yet have the ability to do the country or threshold filtering directly, but it is possible that it could some day.  If so, use that instead.

Comment: filtering time zones based on the user country is a great idea, thanks. this case is very useful for me because the user should select a country for successful registration

Comment: ... as long as they can only register "events" within their own country.  If they are *virtual* events (online, by phone, etc.), then you would not want to constrain the country strictly to the one they set in their user registration.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the language the user uses, then find the most populated timezones where that language is used. However, many softwares list them in time-order, which is what you should do, as well as listing the regions with the timezones. It's more of an opinion-based question, but those are the two main ways (okay actually the second is the only main way, but the first could work) to do it.